# Indy FTP Client ftBinary causes error in Put operation

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

Is it possible to use TIdFTP client in controller enpoint? I have tried to use this code in controller action to upload files directly to ftp server, but there is an error in Put procedure:
...

```
FTP := TIdFTP.Create(nil);
FTP.Host := FQDN;
FTP.Username:= 'username' ;
FTP.Password:= 'password';
FTP.TransferType := IdFTPCommon.ftBinary;
FTP.Passive := true;
try
   EnterCriticalSection(CriticalSection);
   FTP.Connect;
   FTP.Login;
   FTP.ChangeDir('/upload');
   FTP.Put(fromFile, toFile, false);
   FTP.Quit;
   FTP.Disconnect;
finally
   FTP.free;
   LeaveCriticalSection(CriticalSection);
end;
```

...
The error is "**Cannot assign a TIdFTPClientIdentifier to a TIdFTPClientIdentifier**"

The error occured after change of TransferType from ftASCII to ftBinary. (binary files are transfered), although ftASCII is working, but JPG files are corrupted.

Maybe there is a coherence (or conflict) with IOHandler used in DMVCFramework (or IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge) context and IdFTP client self.
Is there any solution how to solve this issue?

Normally out of DMVC context, the code is working.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no possible way for this code to trigger that error. That error can only happen if the `TIdFTP.ClientInfo` property is assigned a new object, and there is an RTTI mismatch between the Indy library and a unit that re-declares `TIdFTPClientIdentifier`. But nothing in this code is assigning a new object to the `ClientInfo`, not even internally. Makes me wonder if you have a corrupted install, causing one method to jump into another method by accident.

Comment: BTW, your handling of the `CriticalSection` wrong. And using both `TIdFTP.Quit` and `TIdFTP.Disconnect` is redundant since `Quit` will close the connection.

Comment: The code is part of controller action of REST framework, which uses Indy components in own context. Every action is running in own thread with own context. If another Indy component isnusing connection in this context probably tries to use IOHandler of existing context not own. Could be a problem there? You could be right, the error is impossible, but it ia real. After debuging the error occured in setting the size of file to transmit. File is created with 0 size in destination. FTP server is local.